# Fill the edit user form values on popup without change the ng model - angularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation

Hi  I have table on angular js 1(md-table) and I am using angular material dialogs.
on the dialog i have form:

```
  <input name="name" id="name" ng-model="user.name" ng-required="true" >
```

I want the form will be filled with the value to edit on the popup

the problem is when i change the value on the popup overlay the table also change immediately with 2 way binding.
this is not the behavior i want to achieve , i want to save the edit form only after submit.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

In your Material Dialog's controller, make a copy of your `$scope.user` object and assign it to `$scope.user`

```
$scope.user = angular.copy($scope.user);
```

So that bindings disconnected

Answer (score 1):

Use [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to copy an object to edit...then when you are ready to update the original with the new values use [`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

```
$scope.originalUser = {
   name:'foo',
   age:37
}

$scope.user = angular.copy($scope.originalUser);

$scope.user.name = "bar";

console.log($scope.originalUser.name);// still "foo"

angular.extend($scope.originalUser, $scope.user)

console.log($scope.originalUser.name);//updated to "bar"
```